# why is R slower assigning to a preallocating vector than creating a new vector?

Tags: r, optimization

Why is R slower assigning to a preallocating vector than creating a new vector?

```
N <- 1e8
u <- integer(N)
system.time(u[] <- 1:N)
##user  system elapsed 
##2.295   0.240   2.537 
system.time(u <- 1:N)
##user  system elapsed 
##0.064   0.123   0.188
```

I could see there may be extra copying--R creates a vector with containing 1:N then copies that to u--but I would guess that should only at most double the time. But the difference above is huge.

Comment: My *guess* is that with the latter, R just creates the vector and assigns it to a variable; in the former, it creates the same vector, but now must do some more work to ensure that it has the same length as the indices, and then iterate over each of the indices to assign the specific element of the vector. Said different, the first has to do a lot more work since the assignment could just as easily have gaps, requiring more attention to where the vector goes.

Comment: Probably also try `u[] <- 1:N` for additional comparison....

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi You mean something like "u<-rnorm(1e8)" will only be lazily evaluated, when I try to access u? But I get similar speed with system.time({u <- 1:N; u[4]}) as with system.time(u <- 1:N).

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Unfortunately there is no speed up versus assigning to $U[1:N]$. I will update the question.

Comment: If you really want to understand why subassignment is much slower than assignment, you'll need to study the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/subassign.c). However, I'm not sure why you are surprised.

Comment: @Roland Well, if everyone were to figure out things for themselves eg by pouring through source code, there would be no need for sites like this that leverage the experience of others. I am actually surprised, which is why I asked the question. If it is not surprising to you, perhaps the reason can give me a clue to an answer.

Comment: If you tried writing down algorithms for assignment and subassignment on paper (even if you didn't get everything right) you'd find that the latter needs more steps. So, it must take more time (even if you don't consider whether copies are needed).

Comment: @Roland For a continguous subassignment as in my example, the only overhead I can think of in subassignment vs assignment would not grow with N, as this R example does.

Comment: @Hasse1987: in the first case, there's the cost of creating a vector calling `1:N`, then the vector `u` is fully iterated to be reassigned completely, i.e. at C level a for-loop like: `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) u[i] = replacement[i]` is performed; not to mention the fact that there's a function call to `[<-` with a lot of checks on arguments types and so on. In the second example there's only the cost of creating a vector using `1:N`